# Operating flow switch on a DC voltage

Tags: switches

I plan to buy a low flow switch for my heater protection from Mcmaster (2371K4, 0.1GPM set point). The catalogue says that the switch operates on 120/240VAC supply. Would this switch be able to operate on 14V DC supply and a max 40mA current?

Regards,
DPK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. Perhaps even probably. This really a question for McMaster, as they hide the real manufacturer and the datasheet from their customers. It's fine for simple stuff but for more complex products it becomes a crap shoot.

You want to know the minimum voltage and current for the switch.

Comment: Thanks Spehro..I checked with Mcmaster and they have confirmed switch ratings to be 24VDC and 0.7A.

Comment: @Dave Should be okay. It would be nice to know the *minimum* current rating (not always given) but 14V/40mA is virtually always okay.